# Unable to run vpnc command

Tags: macos, command, cisco, cisco-ios, openvpn-connect

I have installed vpnc with this [guide](https://scinart.github.io/linux/2018/06/01/how-to-install-vpnc-on-MacOS.html)

The installation went fine, but I am unable to run vpnc normally from command line

My content for sbin

[image]

The only way to run vpnc is to navigate to `/usr/local/sbin` then execute `sudo ./vpnc` or `sudo ./vpnc-disconnect`

How can I run from anywhere with just `sudo vpnc` or `sudo vpnc-disconnect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by creating symbolic link to /bin

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/vpnc /usr/local/bin/vpnc

sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/vpnc-disconnect /usr/local/bin/vpnc-disconnect
```